# Python groupby: Custom analysis of each group

Tags: python, group-by

I have an excel file containing rank data. The columns are Id, date, and rank.
I want to find the average time it takes to move from one rank to another. For this purpose, I want to group my dataframe by ID, then sort by time, and then for each pair of consecutive entries, calculate a triplet (rankA, rankB, timeDiff)

For example for the following data

| id | date | rank |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2009 | l1 |
| 2 | 2008 | l2 |
| 1 | 2010 | l2 |
| 2 | 2011 | l3 |
| 1 | 2012 | l3 |

I want to get the triplets (1,2,1), (2,3,3), (2,3,2) corresponding to the rank changes of employee 1 from level 1 to 2, then of employee 2 from level 2 to 3, then of employee 1 from level 2 to 3.
How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
df.sort_values(by=['id', 'year'], inplace=True)
df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
df['year_diff'] = df['year'].diff()
df['rank_id'] = df['rank'].str.split('l').apply(lambda x: int(x[1]))
df['results'] = 0
df['previous_rank'] = 0

def custom_func(df):

    df['year_diff'] = df['year'].diff()

    df_temp = df.iloc[1:]
    df_temp['results'] = df_temp.apply(lambda x: [x['previous_rank'], x['rank_id'], x['year_diff']], axis=1)
    df.iloc[1:] = df_temp
    return df


for _id in df.id.unique():  
    ## For each unique id calculate the tuple
    # and then change the value of the result in the df
    # Note that you pass df.copy to the function and then change the value of the 
    # original df base on the result of the function
    min_rank = int(df.loc[df['id'] == _id]['rank_id'].unique()[0]) - 1 
    max_rank = int(df.loc[df['id'] == _id]['rank_id'].unique()[-1])
    df.loc[df['id'] == _id, 'previous_rank'] = min_rank
    df.loc[(df['id'] == _id) & (df['rank_id']>min_rank+1), 'previous_rank'] = df.loc[(df['id'] == _id) & (df['rank_id']<max_rank), 'rank_id'].tolist()
    df.loc[df['id'] == _id] = custom_func(df.loc[df['id'] == _id].copy())

df = df.loc[df['results'] != 0]
df.loc[:,['id', 'results']].head()
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have read the data into a dataframe `df`, you could try:

```py
res = (
    df
    .sort_values("date")
    .assign(
        rank_b=lambda df: df["rank"].str.lstrip("l").astype("int"),
        rank_a=lambda df: df.groupby("id")["rank_b"].shift(),
        diff=lambda df: df.groupby("id")["date"].diff(),
    )
    .dropna()
    .assign(triplets=lambda df:
        df.apply(lambda r: (int(r.at["rank_a"]), r.at["rank_b"], int(r.at["diff"])), axis=1),
    )
    .drop(columns=["rank_a", "rank_b", "diff"]).reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

- First sort along the `date` column to make sure the following steps connect the rows in the right order (`.shift` and `.diff`).
- Extract the levels as integers from the strings in column `rank` into column `rank_b`.
- Group by `id` and (1) build `rank_a` by shifting the column `rank` once, (2) calculate the year differences, for the groups.
- Drop the rows that have `NaN`s, stemming from the `.shift`/`.diff`.
- Now extract the triplets into tuples (and thereby cast floats to integers).
- Finally drop the auxiliary columns and reset the index (don't do that if you want to keep the old indices for better comparison with the old dataframe).

Result for the sample:

```
   id  date rank   triplets
0   1  2010   l2  (1, 2, 1)
1   2  2011   l3  (2, 3, 3)
2   1  2012   l3  (2, 3, 2)
```